# Rig in T-pose and Cloth in A-pose

Tags: modeling, rigging

I have a rig in T-pose and a cloth in A-pose and I need to match the cloth to the rig. The problem is that I need the rig to stay the same, it can't be changed because we use it in Unity.

[image: T-rig and A-cloth]

And when I change the rig in *Pose Mode* to match the cloth, my hands are moving inwards. Is there a way to quickly match the cloth to the T-pose? Manual editing is very time consuming and the result is not the best.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Separate the shirt from the rest of the character. Select its *Armature* modifier, duplicate it:

[image]

Move the armature in *Pose* mode so that the shirt get the T pose, then apply the modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can sculpt the clothes to do the T pose.
Here a video to show how to [Sculpt T pose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4L6O.jpg) in 60 seconds.
[image]